# A problem occurred configuring project ':lottie-react-native'

Tags: android, react-native, expo, build.gradle, lottie-react-native

I'm working on my react native project, where I've used the lottie-react-native@5.1.6 (as it is the compatible with expo 49).

Now when I'm writing `./gradlew assembleRelease`, I'm getting this error:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':lottie-react-native'.
> Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.api.variant.impl.LibraryVariantBuilderImpl.
   > Namespace not specified. Please specify a namespace in the module's build.gradle file like so:
     
     android {
         namespace 'com.example.namespace'
     }
     
     If the package attribute is specified in the source AndroidManifest.xml, it can be migrated automatically to the namespace value in the build.gradle file using the AGP Upgrade Assistant; please refer to https://developer.android.com/studio/build/agp-upgrade-assistant for more information.
```

However, in my `build.gradle` file, the namespace is already exists. Here is my `android/build.gradle` file's android block:

```
android {
    ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
    namespace 'com.plantdoc.app'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.plantdoc.app'
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
        buildConfigField("boolean", "REACT_NATIVE_UNSTABLE_USE_RUNTIME_SCHEDULER_ALWAYS", (findProperty("reactNative.unstable_useRuntimeSchedulerAlways") ?: true).toString())
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            shrinkResources (findProperty('android.enableShrinkResourcesInReleaseBuilds')?.toBoolean() ?: false)
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help me with this error?

Answer (score 1):

use version 5.1.6 that worked for me
https://www.npmjs.com/package/lottie-react-native/v/5.1.6?activeTab=versions

Answer (score 0):

Change from

```
npm i lottie-react-native
```

To

```
npm i lottie-react-native@5.1.6
```

Working for me at `react-native-template-typescript@6.12.10`